# d3js highlighting connected nodes

Tags: d3.js

I want to list all the nodes that are connected to a node that I rollover with a mouse in a text field, been trying to use the filter function and it sort of does what I need since it affects the stroke width of the linked objects but I'd like to also output the node names too.

```
 .on("mouseover", function(da) {
  link.filter(function(db) { return da.group == db.groupColor; })
  .transition()
  .style("stroke-width", 8);  

 selectedText.text("Currently Selected: "+da.name+"is connecting to sensors: "+link.filter(function(db) { return da.group == db.groupColor; }) );
```

right now I am getting an output of "bike brian is connected to sensors: [object svgline element]"

but what I want is to be able to return all the names of the other nodes... does that make sense? so that it might say "bike brian is connected to sensors: accelerometer, gps, etc..."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your links are using standard network syntax, you could do the following:

```
var filteredLinks = link.filter(function(db) { return da.group == db.groupColor; });
var sensorList = '';
for (x in filteredLinks) {
    if (filteredLinks[x]) {
    filteredLinks[x].source.id == originalSensorID ? sensorList += filteredLinks[x].target.id : sensorList += filteredLinks[x].source.id
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to add commas and spaces to the sensorList variable. It's a bit cumbersome, but I wasn't able to make the .each() method work with a filter, so it's the best I can come up with.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working for me, should I be substituting something for originalSensorID ?

Comment: I am getting "typeError: filteredLinks[x].source is undefined" any ideas why? thanks in advance

Comment: You can test to make sure the for loop is returning an object--I added it above. But if you're not following standard node-link syntax in D3 (which has an array of link objects that have "source" and "target" attributes that point at node objects, then this won't work.

Comment: Hi Elijah, thanks again for helping me with this.. I am following the nodes/link syntax but I get this error "filteredLinks[x].source is undefined"